# JUnit test cases not running through maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

Similar questions have been asked before, but I'm unable to fix this issue.
I want to automate JUnit test case execution through Maven.

```
JUnit jar version - 4.8.2

Maven version - 3.2.5

Surefire jar version - 2.14.1
```

When I ran mvn compile test, I got this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project my_project: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project my_project: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:55)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:733)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
```

These entries are in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>

</dependency>

<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>

</plugin>
```

I've tried all the stuffs from internet but none worked. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have any unit tests or they are in the wrong location

Comment: Couple of thoughts.. 1) try first to remove all mention of surefire and issue "mvn test". 2) rather than configure surefire as a dependency, configure it as a build plugin as shown by Olivier. 3) should be able to get by with test scope on junit dependency rather than compile.

Answer (score 2):

By default, your tests must be in `src/test/java`.

Also, there are some name conventions. The [documentation of the surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) mentions this:

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
> - "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
> - "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

Here's a sample structure you should have.

```
project
+-src
  +-main
  | +-java
  |   + tmp
  |     + App.java
  +-test
  | +-java
  |   +-tmp
  |     + AppTest.java
  +-pom.xml
```

Your `AppTest.java` should have at least one `@org.junit.Test`-annotated method.

```
package tmp;
public class AppTest {
  @org.junit.Test
  public void testSomeMethod() {
    System.out.println("Tests have been found");
  }
}
```

And your pom.xml should be similar to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>tmp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I just tested it and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Tried with both the methods. None worked. Still getting the same exception.

Comment: Then please edit your question and add below the the structure and names of your tests, as well how you defined your junit dependency in Maven.